# Having trouble with composition C++

Tags: c++, list, object, initialization, composition

I'm trying to declare a member-object in a class in C++, like so:

```
class bankAccount
{
public:
  bankAccount(int, int, int, string, int);
private:
  bankBranch homeBranch;
};

bankAccount::bankAccount(int accountNumber, int accountBalance, int homebsbnumber, 
string homeaddress, int homepostcode) : homeBranch(homebsbnumber, homeaddress, homepostcode) {}
class bankBranch
{
public:
/** bankBranch(const int& bsbNumber, const string& address, const int& postCode) 
{ 
    this->bsbNumber = bsbNumber;
    this->address = address;
    this->postCode = postCode;
}; **/

bankBranch(int, string, int);
void setPostCode() 
{ 
    cout << "Please type in the postal code of your bankBranch: " << endl;
    cin >> postCode;
}
void setBsbNumber()
{ 
    cout << "Please type in the BSB Number of your bankBranch: " << endl;
    cin >> bsbNumber;

}
void setAddress() 
{ 
    cout << "Please type in the address of your bankBranch " << endl;
    cin >> address;
}
// Return methods for bsb number, address and post code
int getBsbNumber() 
{
    return this->bsbNumber;
}
string getAddress() 
{
    return this->address;
}
int getPostCode()
{ 
    return this->postCode;
}
private:
  int bsbNumber;
  string address;
  int postCode;
};
bankBranch::bankBranch(int bsbnum, string bankaddress, int bankpostcode) { 

bsbNumber = bsbnum;
address = bankaddress;
postCode = bankpostcode;

}
```

I am getting these erros:

- sytax error : missing ';' before identifier 'homeBranch'
- missing type specifier - int assumed (confused because it is obviously an object?)
- 'bankAccount' : illegal member initialization: 'homebranch' is not a base or member

I have tried many things and cannot seem to fix these errors, could anyone provide me with some insight on how to properly add the member-object bankBranch homeBranch to the class bankAccount? And how to properly use initialization lists.

Comment: Basically take `bankBranch`, move it above `bankAccount`, and refer to the previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is an (almost) single-pass, top-to-bottom language. The compiler must see the declaration of a thing before it's used. Move the definition of class `bankBranch` above that of class `bankAccount`.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the definition of `bankBranch` before your class `bankAccount`. See a live example here: http://ideone.com/LuMzBt

Don't forget to include `string` and `iostream` in you code.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't recognising your BankBranch as a data type. 
Removing the comments might help you.
And defining the bankbranch class before the other class might also help.
Also, it is good practice to define classes in separate header files, then include them separately in all the files. 
Just an advice!